# Cannot get the value of the element in the HTML

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gettext

```
Page.java:
 @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@name='firstName']") WebElement firstName;
.
.
.
.
String nombreActual = firstName.getText() ;
System.out.println(firstName.getText());
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKS2H.png)

The value is required to be able to compare against other value as per below asset statement.

`Assert.assertEquals(nombre,nombreActual);`

Comment: Can you show the HTML for the field that you're trying to find?

Comment: Can you share the error?

Comment: HTML in the CODE LINK (image) you can see all code.  

<div class="" data-v-2fe357a6=""><input class="oxd-input oxd-input--active orangehrm-firstname" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" data-v-844e87dc=""></div>

Comment: Please edit your question to include the HTML, then you can format it and people are more likely to find important information without having to look through the comments.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first post and the English language is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using `.getAttribute()`instead of `.getText()`. Try the below:

`System.out.println(firstName.getAttribute("value"));`

**Note:** Assuming the HTML contains attribute `value` and its content is **rodrigo**

Comment: Grateful for your help.
**Code:**
'String nombreActual = firstName.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("valor de nombre: " + nombre);
System.out.println("nombreActual: " + nombreActual);
Assert.assertEquals(nombre,nombreActual);'

**Result:**
valor de nombre: francisca
nombreActual: francisca

Comment: Glad it helped. If you think this answered solved your issue, accept the answer.